# How do I figure out the right partial imports to use for scalaz 7?

Tags: import, scalaz

With Scalaz 6, the recommended approach for importing was simply importing the entire library (more or less):

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
```

Scalaz 7 now supports more modular imports. But when I am looking at some scalaz source code or scaladocs, it's not obvious what to import. How do I trace back from the actual function or typeclass I want to use, to the right import statement to add to get it?